# Including jMock 2.6.0 in Maven

Tags: maven-2, junit, jmock

I am unable to include the new jMock release as Maven dependency. Here is what I tried including:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried various combinations with the version and artifactId but it doesn't help.

Thanks,
Julia.

Comment: AFAIK, version 2.6.0 isn't final yet, the latest stable version is 2.5.1 and that's the version you can get in Maven Central.

Comment: Hey can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734977/m2eclipse-filtering-test-resources   Thanks, Julia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2.6.0-RC2 can't be found on public Maven repositories yet. You may want to download it manually from [jMock.org download page](http://www.jmock.org/download.html). If your company uses local Maven repository you can [deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) it there. If it's just for your own usage [install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/) it in your local Maven repo.

Comment: I can't deploy it on the company repo as the dev, QA environments and the CI server fall outside it.

Answer (score 4):

**Now superceded - see my other answer**

Just had to solve this problem myself, and I haven't found a simple way :-(

The complicated way is this:

1. Download jmock-2.6.0-RC2-jars.zip and unzip into a directory.
2. Download http://www.oneeyedmen.com/misc/jmock-2.6.0-RC2.poms.zip and unzip into the same directory.
3. Issue the following commands in that directory to install into your local Maven repository

> mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=jmock-2.6.0-RC2.pom -Dfile=jmock-2.6.0-RC2.jar
>
> mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=jmock-legacy-2.6.0-RC2.pom -Dfile=jmock-legacy-2.6.0-RC2.jar
>
> mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=jmock-junit4-2.6.0-RC2.pom -Dfile=jmock-junit4-2.6.0-RC2.jar
>
> mvn install:install-file -DgeneratePom -DgroupId=org.hamcrest -DartifactId=hamcrest-core -Dversion=1.3.0RC1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=hamcrest-core-1.3.0RC1.jar
>
> mvn install:install-file -DgeneratePom -DgroupId=org.hamcrest -DartifactId=hamcrest-library -Dversion=1.3.0RC1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=hamcrest-library-1.3.0RC1.jar
>
> mvn install:install-file -DgeneratePom -DgroupId=org.hamcrest -DartifactId=hamcrest-unit-test -Dversion=1.3.0RC1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=hamcrest-unit-test-1.3.0RC1.jar

Then you should be able to use jmock jmock-junit4 and jmock-legacy at version 2.6.0-RC2, with Junit 4.8.1

Caveats - this is entirely unofficial, may conflict horribly with any official jmock poms, may be completely the wrong way to solve this problem, but works for me.

Comment: thanks :) for some reason, i had to install hamcrest-core manually, ie, mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.hamcrest -DartifactId=hamcrest-core -Dversion=1.3.0RC1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=hamcrest-core-1.3.0RC1.jar ...

Answer (score 2):

JMock 2.6.0-RC2 is now [in Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jmock/jmock/2.6.0-RC2)

Answer (score 1):

JMock 2.6.0 is now on Maven Central: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jmock/jmock/2.6.0